# Confusion of the "type-checking" principle in WebAssembly

Tags: webassembly

[image]

I am now digging into the type-checking principle of WebAssembly, here I am not sure why does the value stack can never be smaller than the size at start? The test case shows below:

```
i32.const 1
i32.const 2
block $main
  i32.add
end
```

Any help will be appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you give does not type-check in current Wasm. Inside a block you cannot access operands that where pushed on the stack before the block was entered. Hence the description you quote is correct.

However, this is a restriction we plan to lift soon, see the [proposal for multi-values](https://github.com/WebAssembly/multi-value/blob/master/proposals/multi-value/Overview.md). With that proposal you can write

```
(i32.const 1)
(i32.const 2)
(block (param i32 i32) (result i32)
  (i32.add)
)
```

Note that any operands being passed in or out a block require explicit type annotations.